# Nativescript-dev-appium test has stuck after "Check if emulator is running"

Tags: nativescript, appium-android

Test is stuck after `Check if emulator is running` and sometime later it says `Check has failed`.

Below is the test message

$ npm run e2e -- --runType android28

```
> philgo-v5@0.0.0 e2e /Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5
> tsc -p e2e && mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts --recursive e2e --appiumCapsLocation ./e2e/config/appium.capabilities.json "--runType" "android28"

Parsed args:   {"port":4723,"projectDir":"/Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5","projectBinary":"/Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5/node_modules/.bin","pluginRoot":"/Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5/node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium","pluginBinary":"/Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5/node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/node_modules/.bin","wdaLocalPort":8410,"testFolder":"e2e","runType":"android28","appiumCapsLocation":"./e2e/config/appium.capabilities.json","verbose":false,"cleanApp":false,"path":"/Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5","capabilitiesName":"appium.capabilities.json","driverConfig":{"host":"localhost","port":4723},"logImageTypes":[]}


./e2e/config/appium.capabilities.json
Capabilities found at: ./e2e/config/appium.capabilities.json
Automation name set to: UIAutomator2
To change automation name, you need to set it in appium capabilities!
Available applications:  ["platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"]
Pick first application:   "platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
Application full path: /Users/jaehosong/apps/philgo/philgo-v5/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Executing "/bin/ps aux | grep -ie 'sdk/emulator/qemu' | grep -ie 'Pixel2Api28PieX86' | grep -v grep  | xargs kill -9"
No matching processes to kill!
Starting emulator with options: -avd Pixel2Api28PieX86 -port 5548 ["-no-audio","-no-boot-anim","-wipe-data","-no-snapshot-load","-no-snapshot-save"]
Booting emulator ...
Check if "emulator-5548" is running.
Check has "failed".
```

This is screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because probably you have the wrong version of the emulator installed.

Go to Android Studio (you can actually go directly to the AVD Manager in the SDK folder btw):

1. Open the Android Virtual Device Manager;
2. Create Virtual Device...
3. Select some hardware that you want;
4. Select some image which the **target is "Google APIs" NOT "Google Play"** (Look at "x86 Images" tab);
5. Finish the Virtual Device creation.

Note: I am using Pie, API 28, x86_64 to run my {NS} tests.

FYI, here it is the configuration of `appium.capabilities.json`:

```
"android28": {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "28",
    "deviceName": "Pixel_2_API_28",
    "avd": "Pixel_2_API_28",
    "lt": 60000,
    "newCommandTimeout": 720,
    "noReset": false,
    "fullReset": false,
    "app": ""
}
```